# A sequence $( a_n )$ is defined by $(a_1)=1$, and $a_{n+1}$=$\sqrt {a_n + 1}$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to prove that $( a_n )$ is an increasing sequence by induction?
$n\ge 1$

Comment: If $n\in\mathbb{R}$, then you don't have a sequence.  In fact your definition doesn't even extend to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(for $n=1$) ${{a}_{2}}=\sqrt{2}>1={{a}_{1}}$ so $a_2>a_1$.

*now assume ${{a}_{n+1}}>{{a}_{n}}.$ we know $\sqrt{{{a}_{n}}+1}={{a}_{n+1}}>{{a}_{n}}$

so using

*${a}_{n+1}>{{a}_{n}}$ and

**$\sqrt{{{a}_{n}}+1}={{a}_{n+1}}$ we get
 $${{a}_{n+2}}=\sqrt{{{a}_{n+1}}+1}>\sqrt{{{a}_{n}}+1}={{a}_{n+1}}$$ then $${{a}_{n+2}}>{{a}_{n+1}}$$