# Proof Using the Monotone Convergence Theorem for the sequence $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{4 + a_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, radicals

Consider the recursively defined sequence $a_0 = 1$

$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{4 + a_n}$

How to prove that the sequence converges using the Monotone Convergence Theorem, and find the limit?

Comment: What part of the hypothesis of the theorem are you having trouble with?

Comment: I like this problem

Comment: I think this should be closed as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq

Comment: See also this similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538465/a-sequence-a-n-is-defined-by-a-1-1-and-a-n1-sqrt-a-n-1-f

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see that $a_n>0$ for all $n\geq 1$. Use mathematical induction to prove that $a_n\leq 4$ for all $n\geq1$ and $a_n$ is increasing. Hence $a_n$ is convergent, say its limit is $A$, then $ A=\sqrt{A+4}$ and $A>0$, which give us that $ A=\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- show (by induction) that for all $n \geq 0$, $1\leq  a_n < \frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}$;
- use the right inequality to show that $a_n$ is an increasing sequence;
- use these two points (monotone convergence) to argue that $a_n\nearrow a\in\left(1,\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}\right]$;
- using the fact that the recurrence relation has only two fixed points, and that the limit has to be one of them, find $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. $\{a_n\}$ is strictly increasing, i.e., $a_{n+1}> a_n$.

This is shown inductively. For $n=1$, We have that $$a_2=\sqrt{4+a_1}=\sqrt{4+1}=\sqrt{5}>1=a_1.$$
Assume now that it is true for $n=k$, i.e., $a_{k+1}>a_{k}$. Then $a_{k+1}+4>a_{k}+4$, and hence
$$
a_{k+2}=\sqrt{4+a_{k+1}}>\sqrt{4+a_{k}}=a_{k+1},
$$
and thus it is true for $n=k+1$. Hence indeed, $\{a_n\}$ is increasing.

Step 2. $\{a_n\}$ is upper bounded.

In particular, we shall show that $a_n<3$ inductively. So, for $k=1$, we have that $a_1=1<3$.
Assume that that it is true for $n=k$ and $a_k<3$. Then $a_{k+1}=\sqrt{4+a_k}<\sqrt{4+3}=\sqrt{7}<3$. Thus $\{a_n\}$ is upper bounded by 3.

Step 1.+Step 2. imply that $\{a_n\}$ converges, as an increasing and upper bounded sequence does converge.

Step 3. Finding of the limit of $\{a_n\}$.

Assume that $a_n\to a$, then $a_n+4\to a+4$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+4}\to\sqrt{a+4}$.
But $\{a_n\}$ and $\{a_{n+1}\}$ have the same limit, and hence
$$
a=\sqrt{a+4},
$$
which implies that
$$
a^2-a-4=0,
$$
and hence
$$
a=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{17}}{2}.
$$
The negative root is rejected as the terms of $\{a_n\}$ are positive.
Thus
$$
a_n\to\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}.
$$